# Commodity vs. Currency

Tags: currencies, legal, politics

[Some countries](https://coin.dance/poli#legalitybycountry) view Bitcoin as a commodity, some see it as a currency (and some ban it, but that's another story).

I read a few articles, but in layman's terms, what are the main differences about a **commodity** and a **currency**?

Answer (score 1):

I found this on a [Quora](https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-Bitcoin-being-taxed-as-property-instead-of-currency-by-the-IRS). Hope it helps.

### Property

#### Pro:

It is eligible for long-term capital gains tax treatment, if held for more than one years (which is a huge benefit). The US has very favorable capital gains taxes.

#### Con:

Every purchase made with bitcoin will be a capital gain or a capital loss that must be tracked, even if the purchase price is denominated in bitcoin.

### Currency

#### Pro:

Money spent with bitcoin on bitcoin-priced goods & services would not give rise to a separate taxable transaction. Theoretically one could benefit from bitcoin appreciation and never be taxed upon that appreciation.

#### Con:

Conversion of bitcoin to other currencies would give rise to taxable income, if a gain occurs, and losses would be unrecoverable (for individuals).

---

I think coin.dance (your link) is not 100% up to date.